# Linux ifconfig command ip address , subnet mask permanent

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ifconfig

I would like to change my ip address and subnet mask with the following command:
ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

and

route add default gw 192.168.1.1

when I reboot my linux it's gone. I would like to keep it permanent with this command.
is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the sys V way, you can add

```
/sbin/route add default gw 192.178.1.1
```

to /etc/rc.d/rc.local . Although, editing the initi scripts as qweet points out is better.

Answer (score 3):

The `ifcfg` script contains permanent details of your internet devices. You can find them in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<devicetype><num>`.   There, you should alter/add the following to `ifcfg-eth1`:

```
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.2 
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

Which should do the trick. To see the changes in effect, do a `sudo /etc/init.d/network restart`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link will help. [static IP tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-a-static-ip-address-tutorial/)